# Sum of the roots of an equation $\cos x=1-\frac{x[x]}{2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Find the sum of the roots of the following equation
> $$\cos x=1-\frac{x[x]}{2}$$
> I know the sum of the roots of the given equation is zero, I could prove it by using numerical method and confirmed it with wolfram alpha. I do not know how to do it algebraically.

Comment: Did you actually mean $1-x\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}2\;$ or maybe $\;\frac{1-x\lfloor x\rfloor}2\;$ ? Or perhaps something else? Is that $\;[x]\;$ actually the floor function?

Comment: THE FIRST ONE  IS

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that $$-1\leq \cos x\leq 1\implies 0\leq x[x]\leq 4$$

> Let $k=[x]\in \mathbb{Z}$ then $x=k+r$ where $0\leq r<1$ then $$k^2\leq x[x] =k^2+kr <k^2+k$$

> So $k(k+1)>0$ which is true for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{-1,0\}$

> And $k^2\leq 4$ so $k\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$. Thus $\boxed{k\in\{-2,1,2\}}$.

> - If $k=2$ we get $x=2+r$ so $0\leq 4+2r\leq 4$ so $r\leq 0$ so $r=0$ and thus $x=2$ which does not work since $\cos 2\ne -1$.

> - If $k=1$ we get $x=1+r$ so $$2\cos (r+1)=  1-r$$ This one needs to solved with some aproximation formula...

> - If $k=-2$ we get $x=-2+r$ so $$\cos (r-2)=  r-1$$ This one needs to be solved with some aproximation formula also...

Answer (score 1):

as a hint
$$\cos x=1-x[x]/2\\
x[x]/2 =1-\cos x\\x[x]/2 =2\sin ^2(\frac x2)\\x[x]=4\sin ^2(\frac x2)\leq4 \to\\x[x]\leq2$$ it means that suffice you try on below intervals
$$-2\leq x <-1 \to no-solution\\
-1\leq x <0 \to no-solution\\0\leq x <1 \to x=0 \checkmark\\
1\leq x <2 \to there-is-one-solution\\$$

Comment: 1<x<2 there is one solution

Comment: Mr. Khosrotash - how can I cntact u?

Comment: @Keon: HI , do you mean by phone number? or social media? If you are in Instagram please  search for #khosrotash , my id is prof_khosrotash.

Comment: @Keon: email:amoodarya@yahoo.com